# Rails 3 - How to comment in a View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the Rails 3 way to comment out One Line or Multiple lines of code in a View? And so it doesn't show up in the HTML Source

Answer (score 20):

To comment out a single line ob ruby code use

```
<%# code %>
or for multiple lines
<%
=begin
 your code
=end
%>
```

EDIT:
Here a example to comment out a loop in an view.
The =begin and =end must stand directly at the beginning of the line.
There couldn't be any spaces or tabs.

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<%
=begin 
%>
<%@posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.text %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<%
=end
%>
</table>
```

Comment: Check this out it doesn't work, it still shows a list of %>  on the page; <%# <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td> %>

Comment: Thanks for the example, in the above, how would you comment out JUST the Destory line?

Comment: I updated my post above, the comments are a bit confusing because you can see no newlines.

Comment: Can you update your post to show how to comment out JUST the Destory line?

Comment: you can wrap this line with the =begin =end tags like in the edited example code.
another (dirty) solution is to use a false condition e.g. 
<% if 1 == 2 %><td><% link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td><% end %>
then you can write it in a single line. but be careful, with this method you can't directly see that the code is commented out.

Answer (score 5):

**Rails 3 line comment within a view**:

The *f.label :name* line has been commented out:

```
<%= form_for(@usr) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%#= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>
```

Because this is a view, the # must be within <% and %>.

**Rails 3 multi-line comment within a view**:

*Begin multi-line comment*:

```
<%
=begin
%>
```

*End multi-line comment*:

```
<%
=end
%>
```

Below, the *entire* form_for block has been commented out:

```
<%
=begin
%>

<%= form_for(@usr) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>
<% end %>

<%
=end
%>
```

Do take note, for the multi-line comment tags to work, there can be no spaces or tabs in front of **=begin** or **=end**. They need to be at the very beginning of a line, or they will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I do to hide comments from HTML (...whatever, it works!)

#### in your helpers/application.rb file:

```
def comment
    # use this keyword in the views, to comment-out stuff...
end
```

#### in your view:

```
<h3><% comment = "my Rails-y something something here will not be visible to HTML.
    I don't know why I have to comment stuff out in this manner.
    It's probably not the 'Rails Way' but ...it works for me.
    It would be nice if Rails 3 had some kind of comment-out feature like <%## %> or <%-- --%>  or something like that...
    Ah, well... 
    At least they won't be able to 'View Source' and read this comment! ;]
" %></h3>
```

#### what 'View Source' shows:

```
<h3></h3>
```

C-YA!

Comment: OOH.. just noticed the date the OP asked this. I really hope he wasn't waiting on me to figure THIS out!

Answer (score 2):

Some ways to comment code

```
<%
=begin
%>

RUBY CODE GOES HERE

<%
=end
%>
```

---

```
<% if false %>

RUBY CODE GOES HERE

<% end %>
```

---

```
<%# RUBY CODE%>
<%#= RUBY CODE%>
```

---

```
<!-- 
HTML CODE
-->
```

---

For RUBY code in.rb files like models/controllers

```
def xyz
  =begin
  blah blah code
  =end
end
```

---

For JS etc

```
/*
Some code
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

which "blocks" do you mean?
html? then you can use 
ruby code? <%# code %>

Comment: Sorry not blocks, just how to comment out a Line or LInes, in a non-HTML way. I don't want it in the HTML source

Comment: Strange but that doesn't seem to always work... I get a compile error when using it in a view inside a loop like <% @projects.each do |project| %>